# Geolocation in Browser works in 1.6 (Gears) but not in 2.0 (HTML5/W3C)

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, w3c

I tested this both in the emulator and with real devices.

I created this little geolocation experiment site `http://www.bctx.info/wx`.
It works great on my Android 1.6 (Magic, I/O Phone): it prompts the
user to share, returns latitude and longitude, and is snappy. Android 1.6 uses Gears for
this.

I tried it on an up-to-date Droid and a 2.0 emulator image, and
it detects the `navigator.geolocation` element (excellent!) and waits
for the user to share.

However, no popup appears on the device and it cannot proceed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone in question was silently defaulting to the Dolphin browser, which doesn’t support geolocation.

I still can’t explain the emulator issue but for now. . .  .